# Xamarin Forms: RepeaterView not binding the dynamic data but with listView it works

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, repeater

I'm trying to populate a list view with a result returned from the service call.

PFB my XAML code:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
        <!-- Doesn't Work -->
        <repeater:RepeaterView ItemsSource="{Binding DashboardItems}">
                    <repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
            </repeater:RepeaterView>

        <!-- Works -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DashboardItems}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class DashboardSummaryViewModel : BaseViewModel, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<DashboardItem> DashboardItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DashboardItem>();

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();


        GetSummary();
    }

    private void GetSummary(){

        // If I update DashboardItems value here, it even works with repeaterView control 
        var paywithSdk = DependencyService.Get<IPaywithSDK>();
        if (paywithSdk != null)
        {
            paywithSdk.SetListener(new PaywithSDKListener
            {
                OnSuccess = user =>
                {
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                        LoadSummaryDetails(user);
                    }

                },
                OnError = error =>
                {
                    var user = UserDetails.CreateDefault();
                    user.ResponseString = DataContractSerialiser.JsonSerialize(error);
                    //RefreshUserDetails(user);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void LoadSummaryDetails(UserDetails user)
    {
        DashboardItem dashboardItem = new DashboardItem();
        dashboardItem.Tile = new DashboardTile();
        dashboardItem.Tile.Title = "Wallet";
        dashboardItem.Tile.ItemDetailsPage = AppPage.PROFILE_DETAILS;

        dashboardItem.SubTitle = new DashboadTileContent();
        dashboardItem.SubTitle.IsVisible = false;

        dashboardItem.ItemDetailsPageMessage = new DashboadTileContent();
        dashboardItem.ItemDetailsPageMessage.Message = "Click through to view your transactions";
        dashboardItem.ItemDetailsPageMessage.IsVisible = true;

        dashboardItem.StatusType = new DashboadTileContent();
        dashboardItem.StatusType.Message = "Current balance";
        dashboardItem.StatusType.IsVisible = true;

        dashboardItem.StatusValue = new DashboadTileContent();
        dashboardItem.StatusValue.Message = user.TotalBalance.ToString();
        dashboardItem.StatusValue.IsVisible = true;

        dashboardItem.SummaryItems = new DashboardTileSummaryItems();
        dashboardItem.SummaryItems.Items = new List<DashboardTileSummaryItem>();

        foreach(var item in WalletSummaryDetails.UserSalPacks){
            DashboardTileSummaryItem dashboardTileSummaryItem = new DashboardTileSummaryItem();
            dashboardTileSummaryItem.DisplayName = item.DisplayName;
            dashboardTileSummaryItem.Value = Convert.ToString(item.Balance);
            dashboardItem.SummaryItems.Items.Add(dashboardTileSummaryItem);
        }
        dashboardItem.TileSubLinks = new DashboardTileSubLinks();
        dashboardItem.TileSubLinks.Links = new List<DashboardTileSubLink>(){
            new DashboardTileSubLink(){DisplayName = "View Offers", LinkDetailsPage = AppPage.PROFILE_DETAILS},
            new DashboardTileSubLink(){DisplayName = "Report Lost/Stolen", LinkDetailsPage = AppPage.PROFILE_DETAILS}
        };

        dashboardItem.TileSubLinks.IsVisible = true;

        WallterDashboardItem = dashboardItem;

        DashboardItems.Add(dashboardItem);

    }
}
```

DashboardItems is the collection member property which trying to bind in the XAML.

This property value is updated within the OnSuccess call back function of "paywithSdk.SetListener" call. With the updated value, the data is not getting binded to the repeaterView control. The repeater view displays no value binded to the view.

But if I bind this collection property to the ListView control it works and it gets the updated value as in the above XAML code.

My problem is, I want to customise the listItem element with my custom stackLayout controls for which I want to use the repeaterView rather than the ListView control.

Even with repeaterView the value gets binded if the collection value is updated within the same thread call rather than in the call back method call. But I need to bind the repeaterView control with the data updated in the "paywithSdk.SetListener" OnSuccess callback method.

Can one please let me know how to bind the updated data using the repeaterView control.

PFB the repeater view code:

```
namespace XamarinForms.Plugin.Repeater
{
public class RepeaterView : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ItemTemplate),
        typeof(DataTemplate),
        typeof(RepeaterView),
        default(DataTemplate));

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ItemsSource),
        typeof(ICollection),
        typeof(RepeaterView),
        null,
        BindingMode.OneWay,
        propertyChanged: ItemsChanged);

    public RepeaterView()
    {
        Spacing = 0;
    }

    public ICollection ItemsSource
    {
        get => (ICollection)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    protected virtual View ViewFor(object item)
    {
        View view = null;

        if (ItemTemplate != null)
        {
            var content = ItemTemplate.CreateContent();

            view = content is View ? content as View : ((ViewCell)content).View;

            view.BindingContext = item;
        }

        return view;
    }

    private static void ItemsChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = bindable as RepeaterView;

        if (control == null) return;

        control.Children.Clear();

        var items = (ICollection)newValue;

        if (items == null) return;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            control.Children.Add(control.ViewFor(item));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do it work with populating RepeaterView view with native data?

Comment: If I bind the property anywhere outside the OnSuccess callback function, the data gets binded with the repeater view but, if I bind the data within the OnSuccess callback function it doesn't get updated. But the property gets binded if I use the ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that making dynamic changes to the ObservableCollection (e.g. adding/removing items) don't fire the PropertyChangedEvent for the ItemSourceProperty in your RepeaterView class because it's still the same object. Assigning a new instance would fire the event and so on call your ItemsChanged method.

A solution would be to subscribe to ObservableCollection's CollectionChanged event ([see reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8)) which is fired if there are changes to it's items (e.g. adding/removing or clearing whole collection) and then calls your ItemsChanged method to update the view.

This [RepeaterView](https://github.com/Martynnw/Trailmaker.UI/blob/cdd553e7d279dba3344b92a56115ef9105494daf/Trailmaker.UI/Repeater.cs) implementation works fine with the ObservableCollection and perfectly updates the view after changes.

Hope my answer still helps!